# Reactive Form - Pre-Select Dropdown Option with Data from API

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

In Angular 7, I have a reactive form that is used for both creating and editing existing objects. Creating works well.

When editing, the API call returns an object that is used to initialize the FormGroup. Some of these properties are the result of a dropdown selection. How do I pre-select the dropdowns with the FormGroup data?

In the example, I have mocked a Panel or Order Item that we are editing, and it is coming from the "Server", this panel has a substrate property. Think of a substrate like a car. In order to known exactly the car (Tundra SR5), you first must choose the make (Toyota), then the trim (SR5). Similarly, the substrate has two defining properties, the size (4x8), and the thickness (0.75).

The desired effect is that upon loading the form, the dropdowns should already have the correct size, thickness, and substrate selected in the dropdown that matches what the panel has on the "Server"

I have created a StackBlitz with a stripped down version of the feature.

StackBlitz:  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sfusar

component.html

```html
<form [formGroup]="panelForm" *ngIf="!loading">
  <section class="form-block">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="select_size">Size</label>
      <div class="select">
        <select id="select_size" name="select_size" formControlName="size" (ngModelChange)="sizeChange($event)"
            required>
          <option *ngFor="let s of sizes" [ngValue]="s">{{ s.width }} x {{ s.height }}</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="select_thickness">Thickness</label>
      <div class="select">
        <select id="select_thickness" name="select_thickness" formControlName="thickness" (ngModelChange)="thicknessChange($event)"
            required>
          <option *ngFor="let t of thicknesses" [ngValue]="t">{{t.value}}</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="select_substrate">Material</label>
      <div class="select">
        <select id="select_substrate" name="select_substrate" formControlName="substrate"
            required>
          <option *ngFor="let s of substrates" [ngValue]="s">{{s.name}}</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</form>
```

component.ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { OrderItem } from '../classes/order-item';
import { Size } from '../classes/size';
import { Thickness } from '../classes/thickness';
import { SubstrateService } from '../services/substrate.service';
import { OrderItemService } from '../services/order-item.service';
import { SizeService } from '../services/size.service';
import { ThicknessService } from '../services/thickness.service';
import { Substrate } from '../classes/substrate';
import {
  FormGroup,
  FormControl,
  Validators,
  FormArray,
  FormBuilder
} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-order-item-form',
  templateUrl: './order-item-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./order-item-form.component.scss']
})
export class OrderItemFormComponent implements OnInit {        
  panel: OrderItem;
  panelId: number;
  loading: boolean;
  isEdit: boolean;

  sizes = new Array<Size>();
  thicknesses = new Array<Thickness>();
  substrates = new Array<Substrate>();

  selectedSize: Size;
  selectedThickness: Thickness;

  panelForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(
    private substrateService: SubstrateService,
    private sizeService: SizeService,
    private thicknessService: ThicknessService,
    private orderItemService: OrderItemService,
    private fb: FormBuilder
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loading = true;

    // set this to === 1 to invoke the "Edit" panel form and isEdit === true
    this.panelId = 1;

    const sizePromise = this.sizeService.getList().toPromise();
    const thicknessPromise = this.thicknessService.getList().toPromise();

    Promise.all([
      sizePromise,
      thicknessPromise
    ]).then(response => {
        this.sizes = response[0];
        this.thicknesses = response[1];

        this.isEdit = this.panel != null;

        this.orderItemService.getSingle(this.panelId).subscribe(response => {
          this.panel = response;
          this.buildForms();

          console.log(this.panel);
          this.loading = false;
        });        
    });
  }

  buildForms() {
    this.panelForm = new FormGroup({
      size: new FormControl(this.panel.substrate.size, Validators.required),
      thickness: new FormControl(this.panel.substrate.thickness, Validators.required),
      substrate: new FormControl(this.panel.substrate, Validators.required)
    });
  }

  sizeChange(size: Size) {
    if (size != null) {
      this.selectedSize = size;

      if (this.selectedThickness != null) {
        this.getSubstrates();
      }
    } else {
      this.selectedSize = null;
    }
  }

  thicknessChange(thickness: Thickness) {
    if (thickness != null) {
      this.selectedThickness = thickness;

      if (this.selectedSize != null) {
        this.getSubstrates();
      }
    } else {
      this.selectedThickness = null;
    }
  }

  getSubstrates() {
    this.substrateService.filter(this.selectedSize._id, this.selectedThickness._id)
      .toPromise().then(response => {
        this.substrates = response;
      })
      .catch();
  }


  get substrate() {
    return this.panelForm.get('substrate').value as Substrate;
  }

}
```

services

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { Thickness } from '../classes/thickness';
import { Size } from '../classes/size';
import { Substrate } from '../classes/substrate';
import { OrderItem } from '../classes/order-item';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ThicknessService {
    thicknesses: Thickness[] = JSON.parse( `[{ "_id": 1, "value": 0.75 }, 
                                   { "_id": 2, "value": 1 }, 
                                   { "_id": 3, "value": 1.25 }]`);

    public getList(): Observable<Thickness[]> {
      return of(this.thicknesses);
    }

}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SizeService {
    sizes: Size[] = JSON.parse( `[{ "_id": 1, "height": 8, "width": 4 }, 
                                   { "_id": 2, "height": 10, "width": 5 }, 
                                   { "_id": 3, "height": 12, "width": 5 }]`);

    public getList(): Observable<Size[]> {
      return of(this.sizes);
    }

}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SubstrateService {
    substrates: Substrate[] = JSON.parse( `[{
        "_id": 1,
        "name": "MDF",
        "size": { "_id": 1, "height": 8, "width": 4 },
        "thickness": { "_id": 1, "value": 0.75 }
    },
    {
        "_id": 2,
        "name": "PB",
        "size": { "_id": 2, "height": 10, "width": 5 },
        "thickness": { "_id": 2, "value": 1 }
    },
    {
        "_id": 3,
        "name": "WB",
        "size": { "_id": 3, "height": 12, "width": 5 },
        "thickness": { "_id": 3, "value": 1.25 }
    }
]`);

    public filter(sizeId: number, thicknessId: number): Observable<Substrate[]> {
      return of(this.substrates.filter(s => s.size._id === sizeId && s.thickness._id === thicknessId));
    }
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class OrderItemService {
    orderItem: OrderItem = JSON.parse( `{ "substrate": {
        "_id": 2,
        "name": "PB",
        "size": { "_id": 2, "height": 10, "width": 5 },
        "thickness": { "_id": 2, "value": 1 }
    } }`);

    newItem = new OrderItem();

    public getSingle(id: number): Observable<OrderItem> {
      if (id === 1) return of(this.orderItem);
      return of(this.newItem);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've supplied an answer. We previously talked about a minimum reproducible example. Your example can be shortened greatly: e.g. you could remove the `ThicknessService` and `SubstrateService` and all associated code. Basically your question boils down to: How do I bind an object to an HTML select with Angular Reactive Forms?

Comment: @DavidWalschots According to the definition of MCVE, I need to provide everything needed to reproduce the problem -- hence the "Complete". You can't reproduce the problem if you don't have all the pieces. I'm actually surprised you didn't say that I needed to include the definition of the objects (Size, Thickness, Substrate, OrderItem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Substrate`, `Size` and `Thickness` are classes. The instances of these classes are different than the instance of e.g. a `Substrate` in your `OrderItem`. Therefore, when you bind `[ngValue]` as you do right now and thereafter set the form value in the model, they won't match.

I suggest making the following changes to your code to make it work. The example is for `Size` only, but can be applied to all three types:

```html
<option *ngFor="let s of sizes" [ngValue]="s._id">{{ s.width }} x {{ s.height }}</option>
```

```js
this.panelForm = new FormGroup({
  size: new FormControl(this.panel.substrate.size._id, Validators.required),
});
```

Of course you'll then later need to convert that `_id` back to an object (by looking it up in your `sizes` array) should you need it.